# getting the port number of a website

Tags: java, php, c++, port

How can i obtain the port number of a website using  a program. Is there any method / way that i can use to know the port number of a website ?

Or, if i know that my port number `52970` is connected with `212.58.241.131` this ip , can i know the port number with which the port number of my PC is connected ?

Answer (score 2):

The port number for http is port 80 and 443 for ssl.
If you are on windows start up cmd and type netstat -a -b to see what program connects where.
Please elaborate or post an example of what you want to achieve as it's not quite clear to me.
€dit: in php you can find the remote or server port with

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT']
```

or

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']
```

If I am right, you are looking for the remote port.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

for telnet look here :
http://www.geckotribe.com/php-telnet/

Comment: i was asked to use the command `telnet ip portNumber_of_that_ip`

Comment: @program-o-steve, possible for you to answer here?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31332494/serverremote-port-not-giving-value

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to review the concept of port numbers.

By default, HTTP uses [port 80](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_number). So an individual website you visit won't need access to any other port.

[TCP and UDP port numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you are looking for but from a PHP script you can get the port the client uses to connect to your web server with `$_SERVER["REMOTE_PORT"]`

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this helps you at all but the gold standard for scanning ports has to be nmap.

http://nmap.org/

You can scan open ports for a specific IP address.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']."<br/>";
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT']."<br/>";
```

`'SERVER_PORT'`

> The port on the server machine being used by the web server for
>   communication. For default setups, this will be '80'; using SSL, for
>   instance, will change this to whatever your defined secure HTTP port
>   is.

`'REMOTE_PORT'`

> The port being used on the user's machine to communicate with the web
>   server.