# $_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'] not giving value

Tags: php, nginx, port, fastcgi

We have `nginx/1.9.1`

While doing `phpinfo()`, not able to get the values of below parameter.

```
$_SERVER["REMOTE_PORT"] // no value
$_ENV["REMOTE_PORT"]    // no value
```

Though we have below settings in **FastCGI** config file

```
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
```

Can someone guide where's the mistake?

Comment: Here is page that describes setting server variables. Though it has explained about https, but may point you in right direction. https://ma.ttias.be/setting-https-server-variables-in-php-fpm-with-nginx/

Comment: Blog is saying to add HTTPS to fastcgi_param. I have already added "fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT  $remote_port;" it.  Don't Help it. Anyway, thanks for your response.

Comment: it would be helpful if you can share the full config

Comment: @mikhailov, Which variables you want to see?
 fastcgi_conf is same as this url : http://wiki.nginx.org/FullExample

Comment: Have you tried accessing other server variables such as $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']? Ensure you include the conf in your nginx.conf (include fastcgi_params;)

Comment: @Steve_B19, Yes getting all other $_SERVER variable, except REMOTE_PORT. I am sure that, I have included fastcgi_params to nginx.conf

Comment: A couple of ideas :
- the fastcgi config file is not included in the site config file
- something is wrong in the site config file (not the fastcgi config)
- you're behind a proxy

Comment: @Julien, can you guess what should wrong in site config?

Comment: @NikoJojo can you show me your site config and how this file is being included  ?

Comment: @Strik3r, you mean, want to see nginx.conf & how fast_cgi parameter file included in it?